# MVC3 Handler.ashx

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, handler

Hi I am calling a Handler.ashx from ActionResult

```
 ViewBag.IMG = "Handler.ashx?img=" + imagetest +
```

, if the ActionResult is Index it works fine,

```
http://localhost:11111/ImageHandler.ashx?img=image
```

however if it is any other name, it does not call the Handler!!

```
http://localhost:11111/ActionReult(name)/ImageHandler.ashx?img=image
```

It adds the ActionResult name in the url.

Any Idea, thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us code...  Otherwise saying what is happening is like telling a mechanic whats wrong with your engine my making sounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then i not understand false, .ashx instead, can use controller in return FileContentResult or FileResult to File or FileStreamResult to File.

Sample

```
public FileContentResult Index()
{
    var Resim = new WebClient().DownloadData("https://dosyalar.blob.core.windows.net/dosya/kartalisveris.gif");
    return new FileContentResult(Resim, "image/png"); //* With {.FileDownloadName = "Höbölö"}
}
```

Or

```
public FileResult Index()
{
    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath("~/Content/imgs/fillo_kargo.png"));
    return File(fi.OpenRead, "image/png"); //or .FileDownloadName("Eheheh :)") Return File(fi.OpenRead, "audio/mpeg","Media File")
}
```

so that by variable public

> FileResult Index(string picPath)
>
> FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath("~/Content/imgs/" + picPath +
>   "));

Url : File/Index/fillo_kargo.png